# Div occupying all the space of the margin from another div

Tags: css, html

I have one content div with 960px of width and margin 0 auto (centralized), i want put one div occupying all the space of the left margin, how can i do that?

Comment: you mean... left margin till the window edge?

Comment: yes, the space between left edge of the center div and the left edge from window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oluwos/2/edit)

```
  #container{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;/*change this*/
    margin:0 auto;
    height:200px;
    background:#cf5;
    padding-left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px; /*half the width*/
  }
  #centered{
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    background:#eea;
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="container">  
    <div id="centered">centered</div>  
  </div>
```

HERE: http://jsbin.com/oluwos/3/edit is another way to do it.

Comment: almost perfect, but the center div have a background image in png with transparent background, so in this way the background of container div will apper behind the background of centered div

Comment: @evandrobm I added an additional example to my answer. take a look!

Comment: is there a way to do this without having absolute positioning on #centred ? It might get messy if the content is more than what fits in the browser.

Comment: @evandrobm Sure, just remove `right:-300;` and set `position:relative;` http://jsbin.com/oluwos/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Use display: table, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/yVFzh/

```
<div class="wrapper">
              <div class="left-column">&nbsp;</div>
              <div class="centre"></div>
              <div class="right-column">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>​


            html,
            body{
                width:100%;
            }
            .wrapper{
                display:table;
                width:100%;
            }
            .wrapper > div{
                display: table-cell;
                background: blue;
                height:400px;
            }
            .wrapper .centre{
                width: 960px;
                background: yellow;
            }​
```

Comment: Making some test i thing that your solution will works too, thanks, if the another solution doesn't be crossbrowser i use that :)

Comment: I would use display: table in this situation because the content will grow to fit the page. Try adding a lot of paragraphs to the container to see what I mean.